# NZ function in T-SQL where ValueIfNull is NOT specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, database-migration

I am working on an MS Access to SQL Server Migration project and am currently in the process of converting a complex query into T-SQL from MS Access.
Now I'm quite familiar with how **Nz** works in Access and how a **0** or empty string **" "** is returned if the **valueifnull** argument is not provided.
Source: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

The exception to this rule is if the Nz function is used within a query expression, in which case, the returned value in the event of a null in the **Variant**, is an empty string.

Now, moving onto my actual problem, I am working on converting this Nz-filled query expression into T-SQL using **ISNULL** in T-SQL.
**ISNULL** requires **2** arguments. Both the **Expression** and the **Value**. The latter being an optional argument in Access' Nz, has made it a bit difficult for me to translate the expression. The **Value** argument also needs to match the original data type of the Variant (in SQL Server), this means that I can not just simply add an empty string **" "** as the second argument as Nz in Access does by default.

Take a snippet of the complex query I use in Access compared to what I've written in T-SQL:

***Access***

```
TotalWIP: IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]<0,0,IIf(nz([TotalPurchasesReceived])+ 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,nz([TotalStockAllocated]),0))+IIf((([Accepted 
Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9)-nz([TotalPurchasesReceived])- 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,nz([TotalStockAllocated]),0)))>0,((([Accepted 
Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9)-nz([TotalPurchasesReceived])- 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,nz([TotalStockAllocated]),0)))* 
[PercentageDoneTotal]),0)>([Accepted Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9), 
([Accepted Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9),nz([TotalPurchasesReceived])+ 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,nz([TotalStockAllocated]),0))+IIf((([Accepted 
Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9)-nz([TotalPurchasesReceived])- 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,nz([TotalStockAllocated]),0)))>0,((([Accepted 
Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9)-nz([TotalPurchasesReceived])- 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,nz([TotalStockAllocated]),0)))* 
[PercentageDoneTotal]),0)))
```

***T-SQL***

```
IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]<0,0,
IIf(ISNULL([TotalPurchasesReceived],NULL)+ 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,ISNULL([TotalStockAllocated],NULL),0))+
IIf((([Accepted Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9)- 
ISNULL([TotalPurchasesReceived],NULL)
-(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,ISNULL([TotalStockAllocated],NULL),0)))>0, 
((([Accepted Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9)- 
ISNULL([TotalPurchasesReceived],NULL)- 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,ISNULL([TotalStockAllocated],NULL),0)))* 
[PercentageDoneTotal]),0)>([Accepted Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9), 
([Accepted Price]* 
[OutstandingBalance]*0.9),ISNULL([TotalPurchasesReceived],NULL)+ 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,ISNULL([TotalStockAllocated],NULL),0))+
 IIf((([Accepted Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9)- 
 ISNULL([TotalPurchasesReceived],NULL)- 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,ISNULL([TotalStockAllocated],NULL),0)))>0, 
((([Accepted Price]*[OutstandingBalance]*0.9)- 
ISNULL([TotalPurchasesReceived],NULL)- 
(IIf([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,ISNULL([TotalStockAllocated],NULL),0)))* 
[PercentageDoneTotal]),0))
 ) AS TotalWIP
```

Note the above **NULL** in the T-SQL example. This NULL is not suitable as it is messing up my calculations, I essentially need to mimic **Nz** without a second argument in T-SQL.

Edit:
Without putting the entire query into this question, Here is an expected result for Job Number: 294784 in both MS Access and SQL Server:

Access Results:
[image]

SQL Results:
[image]

Edit 2: have added the edited to add entire code.

Comment: Don't use variant. Post the truth table/expected result.

Comment: That expression for `WIP` seems to return only `0` or `NULL`.  It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Variant as in the initial value in Nz. Not a SQL_Variant.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is only a snippet of the code and not the entire thing. It does not only return 0 or NULL. Im just using this example to try and figure out what to do with Nz in T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Salman A noted, this is a great reason not to use `variant`. But having said that, I *assume* that you are looking for a numeric value, so why not use:

```sql
    IIF([PercentageDoneTotal]<0,0, IIF(ISNULL([TotalPurchasesReceived],0)+ 
      (IIF([PercentageDoneTotal]>0,ISNULL([TotalStockAllocate],0),0))
```

Comment: I am not using SQL variants. Variant is the first argument in MS Access Nz() function.
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

Comment: @RikuDas, Okay, makes sense. But does the substitution of the `NULL` with a `0` work for you in the `ISNULL()` call?

Comment: No it does not work due to how Nz works without arguments look at this example:  The expression 2 + varX will always return a Null value when the Variant varX is Null. However, 2 + Nz(varX) returns 2.

Comment: `2 + ISNULL(NULL, 0)` returns 2... same as `Nz`.

Comment: I know. I have tried using 0 as second argument and the results of the calculation I get are incorrect. Compared to using NULL as the second argument where I am getting the correct calculation as compared to the original data set, but certain results are returning simply NULL.

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere in your T-Sql. `ISNULL(..., 0)` is the correct answer. The `Nz()` documentation is somewhat misleading - if you use it in a calculation, it will return 0 as well, not an empty string. @RikuDas

Comment: The official MS documentation is incorrect? "Note: If you use the Nz function in an expression in a query without using the valueifnull argument, the results will be a zero-length string in the fields that contain null values." (sic)

Source: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

Comment: Yes. Try `SELECT TotalPurchasesReceived, Nz([TotalPurchasesReceived]) + 2` in Access - you will get 2 for the NULL rows, so Nz() returns 0 for the calculation. `"" + 2` would yield an error. @RikuDas

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Andre, this solves my dilemma. Ill look deeper into the difference in results. Maybe one of earlier fields has different values.